# Existing app unable to deploy even though upgrade to heroku 22

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have deployed an app via Heroku back in May 26. However, when I tried to access my heroku app today, there's some errors as shown in the images below. I tried to upgrade to heroku 22 as recommended but the app is still unable to load despite the upgrade being successful. Could someone please help, thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2022-12-04T05:57:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-12-04T05:57:24.507465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=hangmangame17.herokuapp.com request_id=5d10a211-70a5-4fd9-927f-9782898e4625 fwd="219.74.163.20" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: heroku logs in the cli mainly show no web process running

Comment: Could it be related to this https://help.heroku.com/RSBRUH58/removal-of-heroku-free-product-plans-faq ?

Comment: Your logs should be included in your question, not a comment, but based on "heroku logs in the cli mainly show no web process running" I'm marking this as a duplicate.